# How to get value transform rotation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, rotation, transform, return-value

What is the best way to get transform rotation from some element? How to get variables with "deg" alert (15deg) and how to get without "deg" alert (15) ...

```
<div id="myElement" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background:red;  transform: rotate(10deg);"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

```
function myFunction() {
var angledeg = document.getElementById('myElement').value.transform.??
var angle = document.getElementById('myElement').value.transform.??
       alert(angledeg);"
       alert(angle);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code demo:

```js
function myFunction() {
var transform = document.getElementById('myElement').style.transform;
console.log(transform);
}
```

```html
<div id="myElement" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background:red;  transform: rotate(10deg);"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: But what if the code also has a transform: scale (2, 0.5); ?

Comment: In this situation, after you get the transform style property, the left part is to parse the value with some function parseTransformStr(transform), this function will do some string manipulation or regex related.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 #myElement{
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
```

or in Javascript you can try like this

```
object.style.transform="rotate(15deg)";
```